# Derive a new equation from $m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, differentiation

$$m=\frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
$$\implies m^2=\frac{m_0^2}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$
$$\implies m^2c^2-m^2v^2=m_0^2c^2$$

Differentiating the equation,

$$2m \;dm\;c^2-2m\;dm\;v^2-2v\;dv\;m_0^2=0$$

Our book says when we differentiate $m^2c^2-m^2v^2=m_0^2c^2$. We will get the above equation. But, what I understand about Calculus. That I can't derive it anyway. Actually, what we differentiate here? $mass$ or, $velocity$?

Comment: You are considering both mass and velocity to be functions of some parameter (say $t$) by which you're differentiating and then formally cancelling $dt$. But honestly, taking the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ dependence of some other equation and then absorbing that factor into the mass to define some "effective mass" is a piece of nonsense responsible for much confusion.

Comment: What the author has provided I would call a *differential*, not a *derivative*.    As a differential, the question "what we differentiate here? mass or, velocity?" becomes moot.  Sounds like a difference in the meaning of the word "take the derivative*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the best approach to understand this is to consider $m$ and $v$ as functions of some common variable, say, $t$. So, $m=m(t)$ and $v=v(t)$. Try to derive the whole equation with respect to $t$ and the multiply with $dt$ to get rid of the $t$ dependence again.

Comment: So, the equation should look like this, shouldn't it? $$(m(t)c)^2-(m(t)v(t))^2-(m_0c)^2=0$$ But, how can I differentiate $(m_0c)^2$? It is completely constant. Than, it should be 0. But, It isn't 0 in main equation...

Comment: It is! But the second term needs the product rule and gives you the last two terms of your derivative. The $m_0$ in the last term should be just an $m$ though!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested implicitly by @Connor 's comment,
conceptually, it's better to write
$$E=\frac{m_0c^2}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}.$$

You are looking to "take differentials" of both $E$ and $v$ (with $m_0$ and $c$ constants) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function)
which is what @Connor and @Photon are saying.